# How to make creating an array with using two models more efficient?

Tags: python, django

I want to create an array for a specific need.
I have some parameters and I call a model (ProcessType) with this and filter the model with them. After that, I call another model with a time filter and I have to choose the objects that have the same `case_type` (string) name as the ProcessType.
I created a function for that but it's **very slow**.
How can I make it more efficient?

```
def case_groups(self, date_1, date_2, process_group):
    cases = Case.objects.filter(date_created__range=[date_1, date_2])
    process_types = ProcessType.objects.filter(reporting_group__option=process_group)
    report_group = []
    for i in cases:
        for j in process_types:
            if j == i.case_type:
                report_group.append(i)
    print(report_group)
    return report_group
```

Comment: Does your model has any ForeginKey?

Comment: First thing to do is profile the code to discover where it's spending the time, try [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). Without profiling or knowing your data, I can see that the code gets a superset of cases and process_types, then uses an O(i*j) algorithm to filter the cases based on process_types. Use the database to do this filtering. Get the process_types first and use that as an additional filter in your cases query.

Comment: Also ensure that you have supporting indexes for your queries. Lastly, see if you can write a single query which returns your desired result.

Comment: And what about your database? Is it properly configured to handle these queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
report_group = [
    i 
    for i in cases
    for j in process_types
    if j == i.case_type
]
```

Or better:

```
Case.objects.filter(
     date_created__range=[date_1, date_2],
     case_type__in=ProcessType.objects.filter(
         reporting_group__option=process_group
     )
)
```

Or if the models has a ForeginKey:

```
Case.objects.filter(
     date_created__range=[date_1, date_2],
     case_type__reporting_group__option=process_group
)
```